# Driver for printer Epson XP-411 never ends intalling

Tags: printing, epson

My problem is: I've got an Epson XP-411 multifunctional. My computer automatically looks for the drivers and tells me that the driver Epson-201303 is available for installing. Then, it downloads it but never ends installing it! Hours and hours for the installation and finally the driver is never installed.

What is the problem with the the installation of the driver? Do I have more options so I can use my printer?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try installing it from terminal using apt-get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this:

1- Download the file to your distribution.

32 bits:

http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian/dists/lsb3.2/main/binary-i386/epson-inkjet-printer-201203w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_i386.deb

64 bits:

http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian/dists/lsb3.2/main/binary-amd64/epson-inkjet-printer-201203w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb

2- Install it by gdebi or software center.

Requires a set of libraries to be installed.

Comment: Thanks, Kyodake! My problem was solved with your advice. I guess my computer wasn't downloading the right driver... Thanks, really.

Comment: Worked. I had to run `sudo apt --fix-broken install ; sudo dpkg -i epson-inkjet-..._amd64.deb`